# Lebesgue measure continuity.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ such >that $\mu(A)<+\infty$. Demonstrate that the function $$f(x) := \mu(A\cap(-\infty,x])$$
>   is continuous.

I was trying to do the demonstration but I'm not sure how to modify the sets to use the hypothesis of $\mu(A)$.

Comment: For $x < y$, what is $f(y) - f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use the continuity of the measure to show that the sided limits of the function are equal for every $x$.

Comment: Ok, so if I take a sequence ${x_n}$ decreasing and such that $x_n\to x$ the continuity of the measure tell us that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x_n]) = \mu(A\cap(-\infty,x])$$
so we can use both convergences to conclude (the other case is similar), but I still can't see when we use that $\mu(A)<+\infty$

Comment: In order to apply the continuity of the measure to a decreasing collection of sets, you need to have that the first of these sets has finite measure. $\mu(A)< +\infty$ assures $\mu(A \cap (\infty, x_1])$ is finite.

Comment: D'oh! now I see it

Answer (score 2):

you have to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|y - x| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Let $y < x$: $$|f(x) - f(y)| = \mu(A \cap (-\infty,x]) - \mu(A \cap (-\infty,y]) = \mu(A \cap (y,x])$$Note that $A \cap (y,x] \subset (y,x]$. This implies that $\mu(A \cap (y,x]) \le \mu((y,x]) \le \delta$, since the Lebesgue measure of any interval equals its legth (endpoints are irrelevant to this computation!) Then choice $\delta < \epsilon$ to conclude in this case. The case when $y \ge x$ is symmetric, hence the proof is complete.

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Helps a lot!, but I would like to know when is used that $\mu(A)<+\infty$?

Comment: good question, I didn't use it xD now you have a new homework: find out what's wrong with my proof and please explain it to me :D

Comment: $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)$ for $A\subseteq B$ only if $\mu(B)<\infty$

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense. I should have noticed that ahahah, thanks a lot :)